# Generic map function for value transformation in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a map function that work on the string or number type (or any other type). The purpose of this to scope the temporary blocks to restricted for that variable transformation only.

I'm aware that there is a map function for the array. But I'm trying to transform the same for a single variable.

---

Q: What is the need for doing this?

A: The idea came to my mind when I had to transform 5 date-string to different formats in the same function. So for each 1 I have to create the new data object (with different variable names) and then create a string variable that assigns the formatted value. Instead of doing this, If we can do it with any scope for each datestring then, we can also reuse the variable names for the scope (for example, `const date = new Date(datestring)`). The example statement can be written for all if is written in different scope.

---

Q: What I'm trying to achieve?

A: I want to write something like this (for each date):

```
    data['other']['invoiceDateDotFormat'] = data['invoice']['invoiceDate'].map(
      (dateString) => {
        const date = new Date(dateString)
        let str = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
        str += '.' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
        str += '.' + date.getFullYear()
        return str
      },
    )
```

The above code allows me to map a single value to another type. So for example more dates I can do this:

```
    data['other']['invoiceDateDotFormat'] = data['invoice']['invoiceDate'].map(
      (dateString) => {
        const date = new Date(dateString)
        let str = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
        str += '.' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
        str += '.' + date.getFullYear()
        return str
      },
    )
    
    data['other']['purchaseDateDashFormat'] = data['invoice']['purchaseDateDashFormat'].map(
      (dateString) => {
        const date = new Date(dateString)
        let str = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
        str += '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
        str += '-' + date.getFullYear()
        return str
      },
    )
```

Inspired by: Kotlin's scope functions (let, with, etc)

It should look something like this (in mix of kotlin and typescript:

```
  function <T>.map(function f : (T) -> K) : K {
    return f(this)
  }
```

Can anyone help me write a generic function for this?

Comment: The type of `data['invoice']['invoiceDate']` and `data['invoice']['purchaseDateDashFormat']` is `string[]`, right? Can it have anyother type too? If yes, please give an example

Comment: @ShivamSingla I think he means data.invoice.invoiceDate and data.invoice.purchaseDateFormat

Comment: It is of type string (date string)

Comment: Will it always be `string`?

Comment: Yes.. it will always be string

Comment: But I want to write a generic one if possible. That works on all the types

Comment: @kirtan403 that will definitely  not work on "any type". The date constructor takes either only `number` or `string` or `Date` (1-arry Date constructor).

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND52xm)?  I have a hard time understanding how you expect that `map` function to become a method of the objects you care about unless you do it manually. I suppose you could try to modify `Object.prototype`, but that's a BAD IDEA.